# Fortran Extended type overload procedure but use the parent procedure

Tags: fortran, polymorphism, overloading

I wonder if it's possible to have an extended derived type that overload a procedure but still manages to call the "parent" procedure.

Something like (won't work, infinite recursion)

```
module parent_class
  implicit none
  private
    type,public,abstract :: parent
  contains
    procedure,pass(self) :: sub
  end type
contains
  subroutine sub(self)
    class(parent),intent(inout) :: self

    ! Do something here
    write(*,*) 'in parent'
  end subroutine
end module

module child_class
  use parent_class, only: parent
  implicit none
  private
    type,public,extends(parent) :: child
  contains
    procedure,pass(self) :: sub
  end type
contains
  subroutine sub(self)
    class(child),intent(inout) :: self

    ! do something here
    ! ... 
    write(*,*) 'in child'

    call self%sub() ! < this is the parent procedure
  end subroutine
end module

program main
  use child_class
  implicit none

  type(child) :: my_child

  call my_child%sub()
end program
```

One solution is to make `sub` publicly available in `parent_class` module and use it in `child_class` module but I would like to know other solutions.